# belongs_to / has_many association throwing NoMethodError: undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-associations

My code has 3 models, all with a  for belongs_to / has_many association.  It is throwing a NoMethodError when I try to pull tables from my objects' association table with rails console and in my views.

Models in question:

```
class Coin < ActiveRecord::Base
  # If coin is destroyed, so is their market prices
  has_many :market_prices, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :networks, dependent: :destroy
end

class MarketPrice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :coin
end

class Network < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :coin
end
```

Rails console:

```
2.0.0-p247 :004 > Coin.find_by_tag("btc").networkhashrate                                                          Coin Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "coins".* FROM "coins" WHERE "coins"."tag" = 'btc' LIMIT 1                                                                                                                     
NoMethodError: undefined method `networkhashrate' for #<Coin:0x00000005b15030>                                                                                                                             
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activemodel-4.0.0/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:436:in `method_missing'                                                                   
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:131:in `method_missing'                                                                 
        from (irb):4                                                                                                                                                                                       
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'                                                                                        
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'                                                                                         
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'                                                                                     
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'                                                                                                                                                                      
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Another example:

```
2.0.0-p247 :005 > coin = Coin.first                                                                                                                                                                        
  Coin Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "coins".* FROM "coins" ORDER BY "coins"."id" ASC LIMIT 1                                                                                                                       
 => #<Coin id: 1, created_at: "2014-04-02 02:44:01", updated_at: "2014-04-02 02:44:01", tag: "10-5", name: "10-5", website: "">                                                                            
2.0.0-p247 :006 > coin.coin_id                                                                                                                                                                             
NoMethodError: undefined method `coin_id' for #<Coin:0x00000005b1c920>                                                                                                                                     
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activemodel-4.0.0/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:436:in `method_missing'                                                                   
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:131:in `method_missing'                                                                 
        from (irb):6                                                                                                                                                                                       
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'                                                                                        
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'                                                                                         
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'                                                                                     
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'                                                                                                                                                                      
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140402005453) do

  create_table "coins", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "tag"
  end

  create_table "market_prices", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "coin_id"        
  end

  create_table "networks", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "networkhashrate"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "coin_id"
  end

end
```

I'm not able to go in either direction. Example: Coin.find_by_tag("btc").networkhashrate   or Network.find_by_coin_id("83").tag

I have almost the example same setup in another app I have written and it works perfectly.  I've reloaded rails console / restarted my dev environment. Why isn't rails seeing my association I have?

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Coin.find_by_tag("btc").networkhashrate`

`Coin.find_by_tag` returns a Coin. Coins don't have a method called networkhashrate, networks do.

---

`Network.find_by_coin_id("83").tag`

`Network.find_by_coin_id` returns a Network. Networks don't have a method called `tag`, coins do.

Comment: To add: `Coin.find_by_tag("btc").networks.map(&:networkhashrate)` should work, as should `Network.find_by_coin_id("83").coin.tag`; and `coin.coin_id` should be `coin.id`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Can you explain why I couldn't do Coin.find_by_tag("btc").networks.networkhashrate but similar syntax works for Network.find_by_coin_id("83").coin.tag?

Comment: The first example uses `networks` which returns a collection of networks, the second example uses `coin` which returns a single instance of Coin.